# Postgres - Queries are missing in pg_stat_activity view

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to see and capture all queries executed and currently on postgres database. I am using  SELECT pg_stat_activity but very few rows are present in the view.

```
select datname,pid,usename,application_name,client_addr,query_start,query 
from pg_stat_activity 
where datname='mydb'
```

And I noticed one more thing, when I execute a pretty slow query on another query window, it appears in pg_stat_activity  with state 'active' but as soon as the query completes , it disappears from pg_stat_activity view. as per my understanding, pg_stat_activity  is the view to find all activities.

My postgres version is 9.4.

Comment: If the row disappears from pg_stat_activity, it means the connection that was used to run the query was closed after that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, NO. the connection was not closed.

Comment: Then, the session **will** still be visible in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: session is not visible in pg_stat_activity once query is completed. My log_statement is none. should it be set to "all" to solve the problem.

Comment: If the "capture queries" is the main reason, maybe consider to use extension called pg_stat_statements. It's great tool to get overall look what is happening in db.

Comment: This will required to create extension and may need more os memory. My question is about pg_stat_activity. why it is not storing queries on permanent basis.

Comment: `pg_stat_activity` is a view into the current activity of the database.  It is not to be used as a log of which queries were run in the past.  This is especially true with applications that run transactions on the database--often the "last" query run would be `COMMIT`, and the queries run in the transaction will no longer be visible.  If you need a log of which queries were run, then `log_statement` (either `all` or `mod` settings) or `log_min_duration_statement` would be your best bet.  `pg_stat_statements` is good too, if you can afford the depends-on-workload memory footprint